# How I can build dynamic button in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I would like to build a dynamic button, I wrote this code but I don't know How I can pass text, style, and size to this button.

```
import "./button.css";
import React from "react";

const Button = ({
  type,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle,
  buttonSize,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button
          type={type}
          onClick={onClick}
          buttonStyle={buttonStyle}
          buttonSize={buttonSize}
        ></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: You can use the `style` attribute to make an object of key/value pairs for each type, style, and size (look into the ternary operator). Alternatively, you can use [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/), which make making this kind of thing really easy.

If you're looking for classes, just use className to assign it

Comment: I guess that <button> element is don't have buttonStyle and buttonSize property, it just have style and you can pass the style from props like this style={buttonStyle}

Comment: We need to see what your CSS file is, and what possible inputs you want for `type`, `buttonStyle`, and `buttonSize`

Comment: @Samathingamajig I would like to use bootstrap classes such as `btn btn-primary`  or `btn btn-primary btn-lg` for buttonStyle and buttonSize

Comment: @Aida have you considered using the [react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap) library instead of making your own?

Comment: @Samathingamajig I would like to use bootstrap 4.6.0 and my own style, I don't use react-bootstrap

Comment: You can't use properties with two names, like ```background-color``` in react. That must be written with camel case syntax like this: ```<h1 style={{backgroundColor: "lightblue"}}>Hello Style!</h1>```

Comment: Hey @Aida I recommend you to use styled-components where you can create your own dynamic elements and components.

Answer (score 0):

In React, html elements does not have `buttonStyle` and `buttonSize` attribute. The `onClick` attribute and the `type` attribute are valid.

You also need to pass in a props parameter in your Button `Const Button(props)` and add a `style` attribute which will contain your style declarations in key:value pair.

Also in order to be dynamic, your button should have a label. you can achieve this by adding `props.buttonLabel`

Your code should be similar to this code below:

```
 import "./button.css";
 import React from "react";

 const Button = (props) => {
   return(
      <div>
          <div>
                <button 
                     type={props.type} 
                       onClick={props.onClick} 
                        style={props.buttonStyle}
                  >
                        {props.buttonLabel}
                 </button>
            </div>
         </div>
   );
 };

 export default Button;
```

Comment: Many thanks, I wrote this but how can use buttonStyle and buttonSize. `<Button type="button" onClick={()=>console.log("you clicked me")} buttonLabel="Buy Now"  />`

Comment: You can declare a style object that will contain all the style you want for the button for example `const btnStyle = {color: '#fff', backgroundColor: '#4caf50, padding: '30px'}`. Then add it to your Button component `<Button type="button" onClick={() => console.log("you clicked me")} 
buttonStyle={btnStyle} buttonLabel="Buy Now" />`. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution...

```
import "./button.css";
import React from "react";

const Button = ({ parentClassName, buttonLabel, type, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button className={parentClassName} type={type} onClick={onClick}>
          {buttonLabel}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => console.log("you clicked me")}
      buttonLabel="Bye Now"
      parentClassName="btn btn-secondary"
    />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Blockquote
```